# meshlab is there any way to apply a shader to one layer only?

Tags: shader, meshlab

I'm importing two meshes where one is completely contained by the other.

I would like to apply the xray shader to the exterior mesh while leaving the interior mesh opaque. I don't need to export anything as a screen grab of the model will be sufficient.

I'm sorry if this question is dumb, but I cannot seem to get the shader to work on only one mesh. They are separate layers. Any advice is much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the shaders apply to all layers, not just a single mesh.